# react-router-dom hot reloading using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React and React Router. I created an app using `create-react-app`, and hot reloading worked well until I started using `react-router-dom`.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.7.2",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App/App';

const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
};

render();

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/App/App', () => {
        render();
    });
}
```

`App.js`:

```
import ...

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <p className="is-size-1">Home</p>
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/guests" exact component={TodaysGuests} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After encapsulating my app in a `BrowserRouter` component, hot reloading no longer works. I have to restart the server before I can see any changes. Refreshing the page doesn't work.

Is hot reloading possible? Is using something like `react-hot-loader` necessary?

Comment: Can you also share details of TodaysGuests component and the import ... part of your App.js. Your current code seems to work fine in my local. Maybe there is something that I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your index.js with this:

```
import ...

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./App", () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById("root"))
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't seem to work. Using `console.log` I was able to see that the page reloads when I change something in `index.js`, but not in my App component.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server and re-opening the app in the browser? And  is App.js have the same code as you shared above?

Comment: Yes - I updated my `index.js` to include your answer (see edit). I've restarted the Webpack dev server, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to re-import the `App` Component to load the recent changes.

Try changing your `index.js` to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App/App';

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Component />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App/App', () => {
    render(require('./components/App/App').default); // This will make sure the App Component is up to date.
  });
}

render(App);
```

Also, your `App.js` needs to be marked as `hot-exported`. Export it like this:

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
...
...
export default hot(module)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a current working boilerplate I've put together (the setup below may not compatible with the `create-react-app`, as such, you may want to move away from it)...

[Webpack Hot Boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate/tree/hotloaded-dom) (there are several downsides as mentioned in the README notes)

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",

    // Stage 2 https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-stage-2
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",

    // Stage 3
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings"
  ]
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './root';
import './styles/globals/globals.scss';

const renderApp = () => render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

renderApp();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./root', () => renderApp());
}
```

**src/root/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from '../routes';

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

**src/routes/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';

import Home from '../components/Home/Home';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound/NotFound';
import ActiveSession from '../components/ActiveSession/activeSession';

const Routes = () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
    <ActiveSession />
  </div>
);

export default hot(module)(Routes);
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you have some other config that make hot-reloading not work correctly. I have used your code in my project. It still work fine. You no need to use react-hot-reloader for anything. Just check again your code